# C# reading binary data with fixed length ANSI string and serializing it to xml in readable format

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

I am reading data from a binary files with the purpose of converting it to xml.
For this i have class with all the marshaling defined to read it.

The text values are as 32byte fixed length strings - in ANSI korean codepage.

I use XmlSerializer Serialize() to save it as xml.

```
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 32)]
    public byte[] pName;
```

However XmlSerializer only supports base64/hex with byte[].

I cannot use

```
UnmanagedType.ByValTStr
```

Because it does not allow specifying codepage and i get incorrect, corrupt strings like:

> µðÆúÆ®º§¶óÅä³²ÀÚÀå°©1

How can i get the data to read as EUC-KR string or provide a custom serialization for these specific 32 byte arrays to convert it to readable format myself?

In total i am dealing with ~20 files, each with different structure - but usig same 32 byte strings for text.

So manual conversions and looping through nested data with various class structures is not a viable option.

UPDATE: example struct:

```
   [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct ClientData
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public uint index;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public uint serial;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
        public string pName;
        public string StrName { get { return System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("EUC-KR").GetString(pName, 0, 32); } }

    }
```

Comment: What does `MarshalAs` have to do with XML serialisation?

Comment: Unclear what you want to write to your xml file... Xml files (normally) are saved in UTF-8 or UTF-16, so support the whole Unicode. Do you want to save your binary data as (korean) text or you want to save it as binary data? Because in an xml binary data is saved as hex or base64.

Comment: @mjwills - data is loaded from binary with Marchal and then serialized as xml.

So ether getting correct string when Marshaling the data OR when serializing - ether approach would be fine if it works.

Comment: @xanatos 
All of it, the entire struct will be converted into xml - but the text values end up in a unreadable format right now.

It will have mixed data but those 32 byte ansi korean text values should be human readable when i serialize the object.

Comment: @Agony Then put a `public string strName { get { return Encoding.GetEncoding("EUC-KR").GetString(pName); } }`, or do the `GetString` manually. The point is that you must have a `string` property for the `XmlSerializer` to save it as text.

Comment: You can use : Convert.ToBase64String(byte[])

Comment: @xanatos base64 XmlSerializer  Serialize() seems to just skip it.
While the pName still does show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment I wrote, use something like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private static readonly Encoding koreanEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("EUC-KR");

    [XmlIgnore]
    public byte[] pName;

    public string pNameString
    {
        get => koreanEncoding.GetString(pName).TrimEnd('\0');
        set
        {
            var temp = koreanEncoding.GetBytes(value);
            Array.Resize(ref temp, 32);
            pName = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

So create a proxy `pNameString` that transform `pName` and use `[XmlIgnore]` to remove it from the xml. XmlSerializer probably requires both a `get` and a `set` in a property to be serialized.

Comment: Added shorter example struct in the main thread.

When i use Serialize() on it - the field is not added to the xml.

Comment: Seems like setter was mandatory even if you were just serializing.

Also in the example above - temp is undefined.